# How to slice nested dictionary for every key and save in .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to slice this python dictionary.. Its nested dictionary and i want to separate or slice it for every key

```
OrderedDict([('Value1', tensor([[0.0154, -0.0154]])), 
        ('Value2', tensor([[0.0154, -0.0154]])), 
        ('Value3', tensor([[0.0154, -0.0154]])), 
        ('Value4', tensor([-2.1322e-01, -2.1322e-01]))])
```

I want to slice it like for

```
Value1 I want to save it in a Value1.txt file
Value2 I want to save it in a Value2.txt file
Value3 I want to save it in a Value3.txt file
Value3 I want to save it in a Value4.txt file
```

I tried this

```
a1, a2, a3,a4 = np.array_split(dic['A'], 4) # We get our two lists returned. dic['A1'] = a1.tolist() 
dic['A2'] = a2.tolist() 
dic['A3'] = a3.tolist() 
dic['A4'] = a4.tolist()
```

but this is not for nested dictionary and I am not able to slice the dictionary for every key

Answer (score 3):

you can iterate over items of orderedDict and save each `value` in file with `key` name:

```python
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


od = OrderedDict([('Value1',[[0.0154, -0.0154]]), ('Value2',[[0.0154, -0.0154]]), ('Value3',[[0.0154, -0.0154]]), ('Value4',[[-2.1322e-01, -2.122e-01]])])

for k,v in od.items():
    with open(f"{k}.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(v, f)
```

I had to remove the tensor part, but the logic is same for your example.

Comment: i got this error TypeError: Object of type Tensor is not JSON serializable

Comment: Can you prepare the example that produce the given orderedDict ?